# Display HH:mm from decimal (H.m)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, erp

An employee's clock-in time is stored in the database as a decimal

> 4:30 PM stored as 16.50

I would like to use a new database column to convert the decimal to "HH:mm"

> 16.50 displayed as "16:30"

I believe the answer will look something like

```
CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(NVARCHAR,CLOCK_IN_TIME))
```

but the formatting of the output is incorrect, and usually I get the error "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string"

Comment: Are you converting only the time into a datetime? That would require a date as well. Try using the Time data type. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @Kevin see updated answer with seconds... more precise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option

```
Declare @T decimal(10,2) = 7.25
Select Format(DateAdd(SECOND,ceiling((@T/24)*86400),0),'HH:mm')
```

Returns

```
07:15
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . If you are using SQL Server, you can do:

```
dateadd(minute,
        floor(val) * 60 + 100 * (val - floor(val)),
        0)
```

Comment: Thanks. The outputs are now 12:07:48 for input 7:48 (so hours are moving to minutes and minutes are going to seconds), need hours to hours and minutes to minutes

Comment: @Kevin . . . That's funny.  When I tested it, I used `minute` but apparently typed `second` into the answer for some reason.